# Manipulate Single Characters (or Numbers) in a Text File

Tags: java, string, character, text-files

I would like to know, whether it is anyhow possible to change single characters in a text file, if the String length does not change.

Note: I do not want to rewrite the file, since it is very huge! That is way I am looking for an alternative.

*Now Question:*

*1.* Is there a Java way to manipulate a String's characters in a Text File directly?

(The length of the String will stay the same. I just want to change the specific character at a specific place in the String to another one)

Eg:  This: 000**1**,0000,0000;  To:  000**2**,0000,0000; (All I want to do is to change the 1 into a 2)

*2.* Or if there is no Java way, is there any library or so?

(If this was anywhere ask before, please post the link - I could not find something specifically on that; Well only people calming this was not possible)

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the string doesn't change or at least part of it is constant, you should be able to open it up in for instance notepad and go edit > replace and put

```
0001,0000,0000
```

(or whatever the string)
in "find what:"
and

```
0002,0000,0000
```

in "replace with:"
and click replace all

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\FBR\\Desktop\\myfile.txt"));
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.print(line.replace("1", "2"));
    }
    in.close();
```